# Multiple views using sections for SPA using UI-Router and generator-angular

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angular-ui-router, multiple-views

I'm trying to create a SPA using the UI-Router's multiple views functionality but cannot figure it out why my sections are not displayed into the page.

Here's my app setup:

```
    angular
    .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui-router'
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
    url: 'main',

    views: {
        'v1': {
            templateUrl: 'views/v1.html',
            controller: 'V1Ctrl'
        },

        'v2': {
            templateUrl: 'views/v2.html',
            controller: 'V2Ctrl'
        },
        'v3': {
            templateUrl: 'views/v3.html',
            controller: 'V3Ctrl'
        },
        'v4': {
            templateUrl: 'views/V4.html',
            controller: 'V4Ctrl'
        },
        'v5': {
            templateUrl: 'views/v5.html',
            controller: 'V5Ctrl'
        },
        'V6': {
            templateUrl: 'views/V6.html',
            controller: 'V6Ctrl'
        }
      }
     });
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
     });
```

And on my main.html:

```
     <section ui-view="v1" id="v1"></section>
     <section ui-view="v2" id="v2 ></section>
     <section ui-view="v3" id="v3" ></section>
     <section ui-view="v4" id="v4" ></section>
     <section ui-view="v5" id="v5" ></section>
     <section id="v6" ui-view="v6" ></section>
```

I've been stuck on this issue for days and cannot find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uRR0PmNNIm9fFBXxD5xC?p=preview) demoing what you are trying to do. I took out the extras (ngAnimate, ngCookie, etc) for ease of making the Plunker.

Make sure only one `ng-app` declaration exists in your markup. (This is usually put in the `<html>` but can be in the `<body>` as well)

I am not sure if you have this in another file, but the controllers need to be actually defined:

```
  angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    /*********************** 
      Note the use of "template:" is just ease of creating the Plunker. You can use 
      "templateUrl:" and enter the path of your template file, and it will 
       work
    **********************/

    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'v1': {
            template: 'V1',
            controller: 'V1Ctrl'
          },
          'v2': {
            template: 'V2',
            controller: 'V2Ctrl'
          },
          'v3': {
            template: 'V3',
            controller: 'V3Ctrl'
          },
          'v4': {
            template: 'V4',
            controller: 'V4Ctrl'
          },
          'v5': {
            template: 'V5',
            controller: 'V5Ctrl'
          },
          'v6': {
            template: 'V6',
            controller: 'V6Ctrl'
          }
        }
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  })
  .controller("V1Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  })
  .controller("V2Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  })
  .controller("V3Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  })
  .controller("V4Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  })
  .controller("V5Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  })
  .controller("V6Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  });
```

Also, **generator-angular** might be different but when referencing **ui-router** as a dependency, I believe you need to refer to it as `ui.router`.

Lastly, I think you have your `state` and `url` switched:

```
.state('main', {
        url: '/',
```

The `url` property is what will be used to navigate to that particular state. (Don't put a template url there)

Everything else you had looked ok. Please review my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uRR0PmNNIm9fFBXxD5xC?p=preview) and hopefully you get things worked out. Good luck.

**EDIT** Fixed Plunker link

Comment: TrazeK, thanks a lot I did exactly what you said without any luck, switched generator to angular-fullstack but still cannot understand what's the problem. In my web inspector I'm getting: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
State 'main'' is already defined...

Comment: here's what I currently have on  [PLunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsRs2PxgoUPxUR246nwQ?p=preview/ "Plunker")

Comment: I notice in your Plunker, you have `ng-app="myApp"` both in `<html ng-app="myApp">` and `<body ng-app="myApp" id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">`. You only need one and I'd personally use the one in the <html> tag. (remove the one in the <body>). Also, remember to be sure the controller for each view is defined.

Comment: Your plunker also refers to `main.html` in the URL property. You should change that to whatever URL will be used to navigate to the state. (Like "/" for example)

Comment: no, tried everything with no luck, my sections aren't displayed, tried a lot of forums and solutions for the ui-router and cannot find a good answer. I really don't know what else should I try, nothing gets displayed.

Comment: I made some corrections to the Plunker you created [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCwjBOFomXvStAJEl4Sr?p=preview). Please review and if you still have problems, we can take this discussion outside the thread and into the chat.

Comment: You'll notice I left `template: 'views/section1.html'` in there, but it's working. You can change it to `templateUrl` and give the path to your template file in your local project. I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried your code and still the problem persists...it's ok, really appreciate your effort. Also I can't join the chat because I don't have enough points... Have a wonderful day Trazek!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. The Plunker I created in the above comment worked as is. I'll post the entire `app.js` file in the answer.